# Are Remote Notifications delivered as soon as they are received from the server on Android

Tags: android, notifications

Android: Are Remote Notifications delivered as soon as they are received from the server on Android? Also can we schedule a notification on Android?

Comment: you should probably read the docs on notifications. i'm sure they can answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about GCM, yes all notifications aim to get to the recipient as soon as they physically can (network latency etc, which Google cannot control).

No, currently you cannot schedule these. The best you can do is on your server to schedule them with `cron` or something similar

See the dev site for more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html